# How do I make a standalone repeating jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been working on a filter function in jQuery for a simple unordered list. Each list is inside a block with a filter that can be modified in the back-end (Wordpress) to filter out specific strings. The filter also has a reset button to set it back to the original state.

Now I've been asked to make this a repeatable list. Repeating the list itself wasn't a problem but the filter now filters out items in all existing lists.

So the filter does work but it gets a bit overexcited filtering out all elements that have the class `filter-list_item`. I thought adding a number to the class on the parent div on each loop and then adding a for loop in jQuery to target these specific classes would fix this. Hence the `$list_count` and `listCount` variables.   This however does the exact same thing and still affects all lists. I'm not sure why. Any help on how to make it so that the filters only filter out items in their corresponding lists would be much appreciated.

This is the current jQuery for the filter function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

// Content filter
var lists = $(".filter-list").length;

for(var listCount = 0; listCount < lists; ) {

    $(".filter-list-"+listCount).find(".content-filter").change(function() {
      // Retrieve the option value and reset the count to zero
      var search = $(this).val(), count = 0;

      $(".filter-list_item").each(function(){
        // Remove item if it does not match the value
        var string = this.innerText;
        var found = strSearch(search.toLowerCase(), string.toLowerCase());

        if (found) {
          $(this).css("display", "block");
          // Show the list item if the value matches and increase the count by 1
          count++;
        } else {
          $(this).css("display", "none");
        }

        // Show reset button
        if($(this).index() > 0) {
          $(".filter-reset").addClass("active");
        }
      });

      // Update the count
      if(count == 0) {
        $(".filter-select-results").text("No results for " +search);
      } else if(count > 0) {
        $(".filter-select-results").text('');
      }
    });

    // Reset filter
    $(".filter-reset").click(function() {
      $(".content-filter").prop('selectedIndex',0);
      $(".filter-list_item").css("display", "block");
      $(".filter-reset").removeClass("active");
      $(".filter-select-results").text('');
    });

    listCount++;
}
});

// Search function
function strSearch(search, string) {
  var n = string.search(search);

  if(n >= 0) {
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

And this is the PHP used to build the lists

```
<?php
$list_count = 0;
foreach ($layout['list'] as $list) { ?>
    <div class="container filter-list filter-list-<?php echo $list_count++; ?>">
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <h2><?php echo $list['title']; ?></h2>
            <?php echo $list['description'];

            // Content filter
            if($list['content_filter'] == true) { ?>
                <div class="filter-container">
                    <button class="filter-reset"><i class="fa-icon fa fa-undo"></i></button>
                    <select class="content-filter" name="filterselect">
                        <option value="all" disabled selected>Selecteer een locatie</option>
                        <?php foreach($list['filter_options'] as $filter) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $filter['option']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['option']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-select-results"></div>
        <ul class="filter-list_items">
            <?php foreach($list['list_items'] as $list_item) { ?>
                <?php if( $list_item['link'] ) { ?>
                    <li class="filter-list_item"><a href="<?php echo $list_item['link']; ?>" class="<?php echo $filterClass ?>"><?php echo $list_item['item']; ?></a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li class="filter-list_item">
                        <span><?php echo $list_item['item']; ?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for `$(".filter-list-"+listCount)` created? I think you need to change `$(".filter-list_item").each(function(){` to work only on those sub-lists.

Comment: `<div class="container filter-list filter-list-<?php echo $list_count++; ?>">` makes unique classes for each `filter-list` by adding 1 (+1) with every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$(".filter-list_item").each(function(){` with `$(this).closest(".filter-list").find(".filter-list_item").each(function(){`

This is assuming `.content-filter`-element is part of a `.filter-list`. `closest` then navigates to the first parent satisfying the condition. Whether that condition holds is a bit unclear from the php code you showed.

Comment: I tried to keep it short and only show relevant code but noticed I forgot to add the filter in the php, sorry. I added the part where the filter is created to the php. I'll see if what you are suggesting works though. Might be it!

Comment: Yep you fixed it `$(this).closest(".filter-list").find(".filter-list_item").each(function(){` did the trick, thank you!